# How to adjust ring volume on built-in speaker separately from ring volume on headphones?

Tags: calls, volume-control, headphones, volume, speaker

Currently, if I receive a call, it rings in both my (wired) headphones *and* out of my built-in speaker.  I don't want rings to ever come out of my built-in speaker.  I only want to hear rings in my headphones.  I don't want other people to have to hear my ringer, but I want to hear it in my headphones!

It seems all other audio is handled correctly.  For example, if I am listening to a podcast using my headphones, no audio comes out of my built-in speaker (which is great!)  Using the volume buttons only adjusts the headphones volume.  If I unplug my headphones, it switches over to using the built-in speaker automatically.  Moreover, changing the volume while the headphones are unplugged only adjusts the built-in speaker volume; it doesn't forget my headphones volume.  This is exactly how I want my call ringer to work.

Basically, I want to set my built-in speaker ring volume to be 0, and my headphones ring volume to be 100.  How can I do this?

I have a Moto G Power 2022 with Android 11.

Edit: I'm surprised that even with a bounty, no one has any advice.  Is what I want unclear?  (I want the ringer to play in my headphones but **not** from my built-in speaker.)  Is it really that unusual of a desire that it is impossible to accomplish?  Is my problem specific to my particular phone and not Android 11?  Even if you have a partial solution, please let me know what you know.  I'd be happy with a solution that involves an app, as long as it fixes things.

Answer (score 0):

Technically speaking, this cant be done unless you have your headphones in all the time, and plus the notification sound should always play through the headphones if there plugged in

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your meaning about having my headphones plugged in all the time.

You're saying Android 11 does not allow you to play the ringer in the headphones but not from the internal speaker?  That seems... weird.

Comment: What i mean is, you plug in the headphones  / earbuds and never unplug them (unless switching them)

Comment: I still don't understand.  When my headphones are plugged in, the ringer still plays out of my internal speaker.  The ringer plays out of both.  I only want it to play out of my headphones when my headphones are plugged in.  So, plugging in my headphones and leaving them plugged in doesn't fix the problem; if it did, I would do that.